# Library for rendering neural network NEAT

Tags: neural-networks, genetic-algorithms, neat

I just finished my implementation of NEAT and I want to see the phenotype of each genome. Is there a library for displaying a neural network like this?

[image]

Example of my genome syntax:

```
[[0, 11, 0.9154901559275923, 1, 19],
[4, 11, 1.3524964932656411, 1, 19],
[12, 9, -1.755210214894685, 1, 23],
[11, 12, 0.6193383549414015, 1, 23]]
```

Where [In, Out, Weight, Activated?, Innovation]

Comment: Hi Terry, did you find anything resembling this, except for the (annoying and impractical) graphviz visualisation that comes with NEAT py?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but, if you are using Python, have a look at [neat-python](https://neat-society.readthedocs.io/en/latest/neat_overview.html), which is a Python package that implements NEAT and also provides a module, [`visualize`](https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python/blob/master/examples/xor/visualize.py), to *plot the best and average fitness vs. generation, plot the change in species vs. generation, and to show the structure of a network described by a genome*. See [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41752291/3924118), if you encounter any issue while attempting to use this module. See also [this example](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xor_example.html#visualizations).

Have also a look at [this web page](https://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/neat_software/#NEAT), which lists links to many NEAT implementations in different languages, where some of them provide visualization tools.